# C# Compiler Embedded Resources Access

Tags: c#, build, compiler-construction, resources, ico

i need to make a Executable which then makes it's own Executable.

The problem is, i am using embedded resources ..
they need to be inside of the compiled exe also.

So the question is whats wrong here ? :

I am using the following compiler options for the build:

```
cp.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
cp.GenerateExecutable = true;
cp.GenerateInMemory = false;
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");

cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"\\Resources" + "\\IconLib.dll");  

cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources" + "\\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll"); 


cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources" + "\\IconLib.dll");

cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources" + "\\outlook.ico");

cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources" + "\\Source.cs");

cp.CompilerOptions = "/filealign:0x00200 /optimize+ /platform:X86 /debug- /target:winexe";
```

The exe complies the exe fine and the included dll's like Microsoft. and IconLib.dll seem to work , the application can interact but !

When the compiled exe tries to access the resource ,like outlook.ico it crashes.

Here is the call for the Resource:

```
var notification = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
 {
  Visible = true,
  **Icon = Main.Properties.Resources.outlook,**
  BalloonTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info,
  BalloonTipTitle = TT,
  BalloonTipText = Tt,
 };
```

The application crashes when calling that embedded resource.
 How can i fix that ?

namsespace Properties of the destination exe:

```
namespace Main.Properties {
    using System;

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "15.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    internal class Resources {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal Resources() {
        }

        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Main.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

        internal static byte[] IconLib {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("IconLib", resourceCulture);
                return ((byte[])(obj));
            }
        }

        internal static System.Drawing.Icon outlook {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("outlook", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Icon)(obj));
            }
        }

        internal static string Source {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Source", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are the codes for embedding the resources wrong ? 
Is he using another folder for the calls than the resources are ?
do i need to link them ? 
many questions here.

Comment: Is this about making a fraud notification, to mimic MS Outlook one?

Comment: Nope its already able to interact with outlook (ddls) , the message should pop up when done ....no fraud here ... But still why or how do i need to call the embedded resource